# How to wait until a page is loaded before rendering it?

Tags: browser, web, frontend

I am writing a research paper that includes a comparison between two dynamic web apps. Namely, I want to compare the time it takes to accomplish a similar task on both of the apps. I know that one of the two is much more poorly optimized than the other, resulting in very poor page load speed, and I do not want that aspect to interfere with a UX experiment.

As such, I need to block the rendering of a website whose server I do not have access to until it's fully loaded and every resource has been fetched.

It doesn't really matter which browser, as long as it's capable of correctly displaying sites that are kind of modern. Is there any kind of plugin, script or other that I could attach to a browser that would accomplish this?

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for stackoverflow.com

Comment: I looked into the flag suggested by linuxdev2013 as well as a Chrome plugin called [Control Freak](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/control-freak/jgnchehlaggacipokckdlbdemfeohdhc?hl=en). Since the page in question is _really_ poorly built and it first triggers a DOM onload function and then actually correctly renders the page, my task is not easy to accomplish. I am going to try to check for an element via JS to see if it has content, and if so, display the page.

Answer (score 1):

for chrome:

use chrome:/flags to bring up  stale-while-loading(or reloading can do both)

Comment: You suggestion is not clear as I'm not sure what you're talking about.  Please include the exact text of the flag you are referring to, or perhaps a screenshot.

Comment: `stale-while-loading` flag is not present there.

Comment: Enable the stale-while-revalidate cache directive Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
Enable the experimental implementation of the Cache-Control: stale-while-revalidate directive. This permits servers to specify that some resources may be revalidated in the background to improve latency. #enable-stale-while-revalidate